# Python - "\" character

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python. I'm trying to insert in a string a `"\"` character, but if i declare it like this, it takes `\"` as a `"` character.
I also tried to declare, e.g. `fname='\\'`
but it does not work.

What I mean to do is to add to a path `e:\\Others\Contacts` the string `\<filename>`.

May anyone help me?

Comment: Why downvote? I see nothing wrong with that question

Comment: Hi Joker, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a second to learn about code formatting in the edit box. Paste your code as-is, and then highlight it and press Ctrl-K  to format it as code. Otherwise the results can be unexpected, especially with regards to backslashes.

Comment: @Miro: Probably because of the problematic formatting. For example, he wrote `fname='\\'`, but it was rendered as `fname='\'`, and now it's hard to tell what his actual problem is. I agree that downvoting this is not helpful at all (and it doesn't even change anything since he is still at 1 rep).

Comment: was my first post on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: For general information- if you ever need to use double backslashes (for a paragraph end in LaTeX for example), you need to escape both. Use "\\\\".

Answer (score 11):

```
backslash = '\\'
```

You can also use raw [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). Note that there's no way to have a backslash at the end of a raw string literal though.

```
path = r'e:\Others\Contacts'
```

However, instead of fiddling with backslashes, you should use [**`os.path.join`**](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to concatenate paths:

```
import os.path
p = os.path.join('e:', 'Others', 'Contacts', filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` is the escape character. `\'` means `'`. Think about it, how else would you represent `'` in a single quoted string?

To use a `\` character, you need to have `\\` in the string.

Comment: Oops.I totally forgot about that one. Updated.

Comment: it didn't worked, but thank you anyway: i used join method explicated by pihagh;)

Answer (score 1):

```
backslash = '\\'
```

For build filesystem path use crossplatform:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join("e:", "Others", "Contacts")
'e:\Others\Contacts'
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to a file path you should not try to do this by hand but use the standard library. The module that you should look at is [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html). To add directoires to an existing path look at the join method.